# Backbone Model.fetch returns data but does not update model

Tags: backbone.js

I am running into an issue when my Model is fetched from the server. I see the correct JSON returned back from the server in chrome dev tools but the model does not update with the returned values.

```
var listtemplate = new ListTemplateModel.Model({id: id});
listtemplate.fetch();
```

I see the correct data in Chrome dev tools at this point. Here is what comes back from the server:

```
{
  "title": "Template one",
  "id": "template_one",
  "steps": [
    {
      "description": "I love it",
      "id": 1,
      "created_at": "2012-12-24T18:01:48.402Z"
    },
    {
      "description": "This is rubbish!",
      "id": 1,
      "created_at": "2012-12-24T18:01:48.402Z"
    }
  ],
  "created_at": "2012-12-24T18:01:48.402Z"
}
```

but console logging the JSON show me just the default value and the id that was passed in during the model creation.

```
console.log(listtemplate.toJSON());
```

and this returns:

```
{id: "template_one", title: "", steps: Array[0]}
```

My model looks like this (I am using Require.js, hence the Model has been renamed to ListTemplateModel above)

```
var Model = B.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            title: '',
            id: 0,
            steps: []
        },
        urlRoot: 'xxx'
    });
```

Any ideas?

**Edit**
@Amulya's answer set me on the right track and then i discovered "then". Hope this helps someone running into the same issue:

```
listtemplate.fetch().then(function(){
   //update the view
});
```

Comment: @Amulya's answer set me on the right track and then i discovered "then". Hope this helps someone running into the same issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason maybe because you do not wait for the fetch to be completed. Try this:

```
var listtemplate = new ListTemplateModel.Model({id: id});
listtemplate.fetch({
    success: function() {
        // fetch successfully completed
        console.log(listtemplate.toJSON());
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('Failed to fetch!');
    }
});
```

Comment: sweet!! that seems to do it. so will have to have my view rendering stuff in the success callback?

Comment: yes you are right.. you should render the view when on the `success` callback!